# Why System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group has no Name property?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

In c#'s regular expression, we can write a regular expression and assign a name to a group, for example,

```
(?<One>abc)
```

However, in the class System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group, there is no property for the group name.  The only way we can get the name is

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.GetGroupNames()
```

Why can't they put a property in the Group class for the name?  Is there a particular reason for not doing so by design?

**Edit:**
    I came across this question when I tried to use the following function:

```
Regex.Replace(string input,
string pattern,
MatchEvaluator evaluator
)
```

I want to use just the same one evaluator to handle multiple replace based on different regular expressions.  If there is a name property for the group, inside evaluator I would be able to tell which regular expression it is by just look at it's name.  However, there is no such property.

I eventually did it by use a closure and use GetGroupNames but I still think it should have the name property. If the group has no name, the property can be null.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. It would help clarify your question if you posted a code example of the sort of code you wish worked.

Comment: If you created the regex, shouldn't you know what the group names are?

Comment: Unless someone from the design team sees this all we can do is speculate.  My guess is that it's never been seen as important enough to warrant the development and testing time.

Answer (score 4):

The logic behind not giving a `Group` a `Name` in the API is that if you have retrieved the `Group` from `GroupCollection` through the indexer that takes an `int`, then the group is likely not a named one; otherwise, you would probably prefer retrieving it through the indexer taking a `string`.

If, on the other hand, you have retrieved the group through the indexer taking a `string`, then you already know the name of the group.

Comment: Unfortunately, this logic is flawed as there are real-world scenarios where you need a `Name` property. For example, I'm running regexes passed from another component of an application. I don't know at design time what the named groups in the regexes are, but I still need to pull them out to make a Name-Value pair.

Comment: @MgSam [`Regex.GetGroupNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.getgroupnames.aspx) method is useful in this situation.

Comment: Unfortunately that method is not particularly useful.  If what you want is to know for a given `Group` what it's `Name` is, having an array of names (in no guaranteed order) from the `Regex` doesn't do you much good. Especially considering using the static methods on `Regex` are preferable to instantiating it (for caching reasons). It would be possible to offer a `Name` property, as I've been able to retrieve the information via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at [Group Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group(v=vs.110).aspx) implies that the latest version of the class does indeed have a Name property. My experience is that this is available at runtime, but not at compile time(!!) I've asked a question regarding this on MSDN forums [forum question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b632ef0-610d-4e1f-a965-6f179c5cea19/systemtextregularexpressionsgroup-missing-name-property?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: Please read the [**Version Information**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.name.aspx#Anchor_1).

Comment: @user4003407 nailed it for me: NetStandard 2.0 has no Name property.